# Calculating derivative with multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, products, chain-rule

Let z = f(x,y), x = x(t,s) and y = y(t,s) all be twice continously differentiable functions

Try to find $$\frac{\partial z^2}{\partial t^2}$$

I've tried it and only got: 
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Now the next step is

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$

Anyone knows how to use the product and chain rule correctly here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)$

To calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)$

$$ \begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right) \text{by the product rule}\\&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}  +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial t^2} \text{ by the chain rule}\\&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial t^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure? You treat $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ as it only depending on $x$, but in general $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=g(x,y)$ for some $g$, so is, the partial derivative can carry dependence on $y$ too.

Comment: I think for the way the question is written, it is reasonable to assume x and y are independent. But your answer is much more general. I will make the edit.

Comment: The point is better that the partials depend too on both, $x$ and $y$

Comment: Ah, I get your point now, I was wrong, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is systematic considering the (nested) dependence, e.g. $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ is still some function of $x$ and $y$, both functions of $s$ and $t$ that yields $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)$

Its parts:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$

Still:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)=\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2+\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)=\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)^2+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$

And sum them.